# Opening a directory in a mounted disk uses a different icon

Tags: mount, nautilus, files, icons

My home directory is mounted in a different disk than my os.

The consequence of this is when I open the file explorer it uses the icon for the disk explorer:

[image]

Instead of the file icon:

[image]

Is there a way to make it use the later rather than the first?

[image]

This is what `/etc/fstab/` looks like:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=cdafc091-038c-4c65-b60e-45e3ba289523 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=F202-4B38  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/3a922551-dd90-424b-89d2-67c4ca7d44db /home/ auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Comment: What is the mount point of this "home" directory? It sounds like this partition is not mounted automatically.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 21.10

Comment: @user68186 I have a 1 TB disk under /dev/sdc1 mounted at /home

Comment: Is it mounted using `/etc/fstab`? If so, what is the entry?

Comment: @mchid I shared the contents of fstab.

Comment: @Makogan Is there a reason you're using `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` instead of `UUID=` for your home partition?

Comment: I didn;t edit this manually that line must have been inserted by the disks tool, which is what I used to mount my home dir.

Comment: My "home" line in `/etc/fstab` looks much simpler: `UUID=cNNacNNf-eNNN-NNcN-NeNb-NfNNNdbfNNNf /home           ext4    defaults        0       2` I don't know if that will make any difference.

Comment: It's usually recommended to use `UUID=` I think there are probably arguments for both but I've mostly seen `UUID=` and that's what I've always used. Answer below. Probably just change `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` to  `UUID=` but double check that the UUID is correct using `blkid` before you save the file and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like using `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` instead of `UUID=` is causing the problem.

Just to be safe, before you edit `/etc/fstab`, you should verify the UUID using the following command:

```
blkid
```

Then, edit your `/etc/fstab` file to show `UUID=` followed by the UUID you obtained using the previous command (replace if different from the current one listed). Save the file and any unsaved work and reboot to apply the changes.